# How to work with onPause() on google map inside fragment class?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, onpause

I have a google map inside a fragment. If I go to outside of the app while I am using the fragment, on my return I can't see the map. But if I generally move from one fragment to another, there is no problem. I am using navigation drawer, so I have to use the fragment.
                                                                   Any solution would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the part of that fragment related to onPause(). I think I have done some mistakes with the code, plz kindly point that out to me.

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
    final FragmentManager fragManager = this.getFragmentManager();
    final Fragment fragment = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
    if(fragment!=null){
        fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();



    }
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    final FragmentManager fragManager = this.getFragmentManager();
    final Fragment fragment = fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
    if(fragment!=null){
        fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: why to remove map fragment in onPause()..?

Comment: I am new learner, so there is less knowledge to know that. I tried to replace but didn't work, then the other fragment doesn't work. I tried to replace the fragment with R.id.map1. I just don't know what to try now

Comment: comment your onPause() and check.

Comment: It worked to solve my problem, I can see the map after resuming, but the activity gets destroyed after I close the app. It shows illegal exception on the main activity. Now what ?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that Exception . In your fragment where you are showing map, override onDestroyView().

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView(); 
    Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));  
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.remove(fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

And i think you need to start from API 16.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It doesn't work. I needed to change the getSupportFragmentManager to getFragmentManager. I get the same problem, run time exception, main activity gets destroyed

Comment: make sure to use "AppCompatActivity"

Comment: how do I use AppCompatActivity? I am using fragment and I can't leave that, I need it for navigation drawer

Comment: You are using fragment in an activity right. am asking you to extend the activity with AppCompatActivity.

Comment: I can't do that because of the navigation drawer. If I extend AppCompatActivity, my whole class shows many errors. It can't be done. Is there any other way to do that?@gvsharma.

Answer (score 0):

At last I got the solution. Now it's working, the app doesn't crash anymore.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();  
    try{
          MapFragment fragment = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
          FragmentTransaction fragTran = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
          ft.remove(fragment);
          ft.commit();
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
}
```